# ASP.NET Core FileStreamResult sometimes fails with Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'buffer')

Tags: asp.net-core, null, azure-blob-storage, buffer, filestreamresult

ASP.NET Core FileStreamResult sometimes fails when writing big blob (~1gb) to response

```
...
Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(fileName)
Stream stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
return File(stream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

Logged error (occurs inside FileStreamResultExecutor):

```
 System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'buffer')
   at System.Net.Http.HttpBaseStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ReadTimeoutStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetriableStream.RetriableStreamImpl.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetriableStream.RetriableStreamImpl.RetryAsync(Exception exception, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetriableStream.RetriableStreamImpl.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Storage.LazyLoadingReadOnlyStream`1.DownloadInternal(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Storage.LazyLoadingReadOnlyStream`1.ReadInternal(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Storage.LazyLoadingReadOnlyStream`1.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StreamCopyOperationInternal.CopyToAsync(Stream source, Stream destination, Nullable`1 count, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Internal.FileResultHelper.WriteFileAsync(HttpContext context, Stream fileStream, RangeItemHeaderValue range, Int64 rangeLength)
```

Platform: Windows, .NET 6

Answer (score 0):

> As per the error message, it is due to buffer is null, when the `FileStreamResultExecutor` is trying to read from it.
> You can resolve it by increasing the buffer size.

Another approach is to check if the stream is null before passing it to the `FileStreamResult`.
You can add a null check before returning the `FileStreamResult` to ensure that the stream is not null.

To check if the stream is null before returning the `FileStreamResult`

```
Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(fileName) Stream stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); if (stream == null) 
{ 
// handle null stream 
} 
return File(stream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet,fileName);
```

You can increase the buffer size by setting the `ResponseBufferSize` property in the `KestrelServerOptions`
Set the `ResponseBufferSize` property to 1 GB.

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
                options.Limits.MinResponseDataRate = null;
                options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = null;
                options.Limits.MaxResponseBufferSize = 1073741824; // 1 GB
            });
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Another approach

You can use the `PushStreamContent` class instead of `FileStreamResult` to stream the file to the response.

**PushStreamContent**

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile()
{
    var blob = container.GetBlobClient(fileName);
    var stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new PushStreamContent(async (outputStream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
            outputStream.Close();
        })
    };
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = fileName
    };
    return new HttpResponseMessageResult(response);
}
```

For further information refer to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-tune-upload-download).

Comment: This answer make no sense to me. I experience the same error . Per the stack trace, the error happens deep down the Azure Storage library, I have no access to the buffer used there.